# Gunicorn - Can't start flask - import error

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying out gunicorn. I have a virtual environment for all the packages my Flask application needs, and I've install gunicorn there.

My directory structure is like:

```
|-venv
|-issuebox
|----__init__.py
```

The flask app is in the **init**.py

After I activate my virtual environment, I'm running the following command to try and get gunicorn running:

```
gunicorn issuebox:app  -b localhost:8000
```

But I'm getting import errors:

```
from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: No module named flask
```

The flask package is definitely installed in my virtual environment and I can run the application through the flask development server no problem.

The output of pip freeze on my virtual environment:

```
alembic==0.8.2
boto==2.38.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Migrate==1.5.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
Mako==1.0.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
py-bcrypt==0.4
PyMySQL==0.6.6
python-editor==0.4
requests==2.7.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.8
Werkzeug==0.10.4
```

Any body know what's going on here? :)

Comment: Is the gunicorn running from the virtualenv or the system? Do you have gunicorn installed as a system package?

Comment: Gunincorn is installed in my virtual environment. not my system

Comment: Can you show the output of pip freeze from inside your virtualenv?

Comment: Okay one more question: Is your `__init__.py` just inside issuebox or is it nested inside some other folder?

Comment: It's right inside issuebox as illustrated above

Comment: I am able to run in gunicorn with almost the same configuration. Maybe something's wrong with the way you have install the virtualenv

Comment: If something was wrong with my venv, I wouldn't be able to run the flask dev server.

Comment: oh no, no all I meant is there seems to be some mismatch between the packages being used. It seems either Flask is a system package and gunicorn is in venv or vice versa, and gunicorn is not able to locate the flask package. You can try installing venv with the `--no-system-packages` and try again